# How do you Generating Classes for Java 6 and 7 from Gradle within the Same Build Script Using the Appropriate JDK for each Build?

Tags: java, build, gradle, build-process, build-automation

I want to generate class file for Java 6 and 7 in one build process. Also to ensure that the classes are indeed compatible, I want to compilation the different versions using the respective JDKs.

To summarize the parts of my question:
1) How do you build targeting different class version in Gradle in the same build file?
2) How do I ensure that the respective JDKs are used in the process?

Comment: Use only the Java 6 JDK, and the generated classes will also be compatible with Java 7. Java 8 still runs class files compiled with Java 1.0 without any problem.

Comment: This may not be the most optimal solution.

Comment: You'll have to elaborate to convince me that it isn't. What is non-optimal about it? Have you ever seen any Java library that offers two identical versions, except one is compiled with Java 6 and one is compiled with Java 7? I haven't.